# Python csv text manipulation

Tags: python, csv

I want to combine combine fields from an input .csv file  for output to a .csv file, and some contain commas.  Here is my code, simplified

```
outfile = open('output.csv', 'w')

#these values are made up for this example; normally they would be read from
#a csv and passed to the following 'combine()' function

a = "John"  
b = ",Jr."  

def combine(a, b):  
    if a == "":  
        pass  #don't write anything if the field is empty
    else:  
        outfile.write(a)  
    if b =="":  
        pass  
    else:  
        outfile.write(b)
```

If b starts with a comma, how do I make the output "John, Jr." ?  I have tried using the csv.writer writerow() but it puts a comma delimiter between each character.  I have tried defining an `escapechar` but it just outputs "John \" , "Jr."  Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to know details about CSV, there is a spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

In general it states the following
"Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes."

"If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote."

Implementations like Excel always put all field values into double quotes.

If you open a file for read or write you can specify the type of quoting directly

```
mcvs = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'wb'), quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

will always add quotes to the around the field value.

For all possible values look at the python documentation

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv

Comment: I had solved it by manually double quoting around the entire "name" output field.  I like this better because it makes my code more readable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`csv.writer` allows you to [add a `quoting` keyword](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) which can be used to control how things are quoted.

You probably want something like `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
...     writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
...     writer.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
...     writer.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`csv.writer writerow()` expects a list of values:

```
foo.writerow(['John', ',Jr.'])
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to stick with pure Python:

```
resultStr = a+b
if ',' in resultStr: resultStr= '"' + resultStr + '"'
```

Comment: This is very similar to the solution I used.  I will be rewriting the script to specify quoting everything as mentioned it sebs post above.